How to use a bottom sheet?
So I'm on Conversational AI design project for a mobile app and wanted to know if a bottom sheet can be used in a chat?

I don't know of any examples of a bottom sheet being used in chat, haven't seen it anywhere. The mobile keyboard already takes priority of the bottom region, plus depending on phone/setup there could be other controls (back, etc) in that region.
Maybe instead of asking can a bottom sheet be used in chat, you should ask where would users want the info? Should this be displayed in a bottom sheet? What other UI elements could be appropriate? How does this info compare to the chat, keyboard and other elements in terms of priority?
Can a bottom sheet be used in chat? Sure
Should a bottom sheet be used in chat? Very likely not
Would a bottom sheet in chat make sense for your specific users and user case? That's the question you need to answer
